# Existence of harmonic symplectic structure on symplectic Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

This post is  an  expanded  version of  [this  MSE post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922092/existence-of-harmonic-symplectic-structure-on-a-symplectic-manifold-which-is-co)

---

Assume that  $(M, \omega)$  is  a  symplectic  manifold which is  equiped with a  Riemannian  metric.

> Is there  a  symplectic structure $\omega '$  which is a harmonic  $2$-form? Can one  choose such a  $\omega'$  such that it would  be  de  Rham cohomolgue to the initial form $\omega$?

We  consider  the  following  particular  case:

For  a  Riemannian  manifold  $(M,g)$,  we equip the  tangent  bundle  $TM$  with the  Sasaki  metric  $g_s$  and the  natural symplectic  structure $\omega $ arising  from the  canonical structure on the  cotangent  bundle.

> Under  which  conditions on the  Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, is the  symplectic $2$-form $\omega$   a  harmonic form on  $(TM,g_s)$?

Comment: This is always true on a Kahler manifold: see eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242857/kähler-form-is-harmonic) (the comment on the first answer is also relevant).

Comment: @MikeMiller  thanks for your great comments.

Comment: Concerning your first question, whether on a symplectic manifold with given metric $g$ there always exists a harmonic symplectic form, I believe the answer should be negative. Though I don't know how to construct an example and don't know a reference. However, if you read what is written in 0.2.B' of Gromov's famous article https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/945.pdf , it looks like he doesn't rule out the possibility that for some metrics on $\mathbb CP^2$ the harmonic two-form (unique up to scale) will vanish somewhere.